# If $f(x) \lvert f(x^m) (m \gt 1)$, then every root of $f$ must be $0$ or a root of unity.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ satisfies $f(x)\ \lvert\ f(x^m)\ (m \gt 1)$, prove that every root of $f$ is either $0$ or a root of unity.

My idea: let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$, show that $\alpha^{q} = \alpha$ for some natural number $q$.
  Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$, then so is $\alpha^{m}$, because $f(x)\ \lvert\ f(x^m)$. Apply this fact repeatedly, it follows that the sequence
$$\alpha, \alpha^{m},\alpha^{m^2},\dots$$
contains only roots of $f$, therefore must contain a loop. That is, there is some $\beta = \alpha^{m^p}$ and a natural number $q$ such that $\beta^{q} = \beta$, thus either $\beta = 0$ or $\beta^{q-1} = 1$.

But how to show that $\alpha$ is also contained in this loop?

Comment: Why do you need it? Your $\beta$ is a root of unity and $\alpha$ is a root of $\beta$ (or both are $0$).

Comment: @egreg You're right...I was so close to the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me complete your proof: There's $p$ and $q$ such that

$$\alpha^{m^p}=\alpha^{m^q}$$
and if $\alpha\ne0$ then
$$\alpha^{m^q-m^p}=1$$
and this is the needed result.

Answer (score 1):

You have proved that $\beta$ is either $0$ or a root of unity. But $\alpha$ is a root of $\beta$, so either $0$ or a root of unity as well.